# jQuery method .find() with special character (&)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a "Syntax error, unrecognized expression" when running the following jQuery:

```js
$element = $('.header__navigation .menu-item > .megamenu__item__link:focus');
var href = $element.attr('href');   // Example: #one-&-two

$('#mega-menu').find(href).toggleClass('active'); // it breaks here
```

What options do I have where the href value would be `#one-&-two` and I'm trying to toggle the class on an element within a div#mega-menu with `id="#one-&-two"` ?

I've tried escaping the '&' character in the "href" variable like below:

```
$('#mega-menu').find(href.replace('/&/g','&amp;')).toggleClass('active');
```

Maybe an alternative to find() that can take an input like `#one-&-two` ?

Comment: `#one-&-two` is not a valid id. Again `id="#one-&-two"` doesn't look valid. It cannot start with `#`.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman The # character would work in jQuery .find() . It's the & character that jQuery doesn't like.

Comment: Okay, got it. Glad it worked for you from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$('#mega-menu').find("[id='"+ href.substring(1) +"']").toggleClass('active');
```

See for example following snippet:

```js
  var href = $('a.link').attr('href');   

       
  $('div.some-class').find("[id='"+ href.substring(1) +"']").text('sss');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
     <a class="link" href="#one-&-two"></a>
     <span id="one-&-two"></span>
 </div>
```